# Error occurring while binding key with java application in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

So recently I'm working on a project where I have to bind  some keys with jbuttons to perform a respected action. But I'm getting an error and I'm not sure what it is and how to solve it. 
[image: Here is the screenshot of my code and error]

Comment: Don't post code as images. Post the relevant code and error as text. BTW the error is clear, you didn't import the `KeyEvent` class

Comment: Well, I don't think if texts are better than images. When images can be used to show the exact error and code at the same time than what can be better than that.